# What's the best way to set up Magento on an Apple Silicon?

Tags: magento2, docker

Has anyone set up Magento 2 on an Apple Silicon with all its dependencies like Elasticsearch, Varnish, Redis, etc.?

Currently there are various ways like [Magento Cloud Docker](https://devdocs.magento.com/cloud/docker/docker-development.html), [Docker Magento](https://github.com/markshust/docker-magento), [Warden Dev](https://warden.dev/) (all docker based), MAMP, and native to set up on an `x86` based system (existing Linux, Windows, and macOS).

From what I hear, Docker images aren't all supported on the M1 architecture so setting up with Docker isn't really possible. Some folks have set it up on MAMP, but my ideal set up would involve a Docker setup to manage the dependencies as easy as possible.

Related links

- https://github.com/markshust/docker-magento/issues/396
- https://github.com/magento/magento-cloud-docker/issues/326
- https://github.com/davidalger/warden/issues/399

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I'm looking to upgrade my computer and trying to determine if the M1 is a decent choice right now for Magento 2 development.

Comment: Yes! There's been massive progress on this. Please check my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/markshust/docker-magento now officially supports both Intel and Apple Silicon machines.

I've also created a fork of Warden at https://github.com/drpayyne/warden-multi-arch which supports Apple Silicon.